# GUI Tool to Search for File in Subversion Repository

Tags: svn, file, user-interface, search, find

Hi is there any graphical tool for searching for a file in a a SVN Repository based on the **file name** or its **contents**? I mean something GUI based so grep is not an option. I'm referring to something like the file search option you get in Microsoft Visual Source Safe. I'm currently using tortoise svn and Ankh SVN for Visual Studio 2010. But none of them have the search for file feature as far as I know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

What you'll get is a web GUI to dot his along with a server-side indexer.

[FishEye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/tour/code-search.jsp) from Altassian is good (not free),  but there's also [svn-search](http://sourceforge.net/projects/svn-search/) and [svnquery](http://svnquery.tigris.org/) and [opengrok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/).

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! svnquery was the best solution for me as it is free and it has a .net winforms based interface called svnfind. However i had to configure visual svn server as mentioned here to allow readonly annonymous access to allow svnfind to open results when links are clicked. http://geekswithblogs.net/robz/archive/2008/10/04/enhancing-visual-svn-to-allow-anonymous-access.aspx

Comment: Its pretty pathetic imho that for such a famous technology so little GUI tools exist (which you have to do manual configuration to get working too) as far as repository searching is concerened. Even the old Visual Source Safe had a built in GUI search option which was simple and thorough.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search with just path / filename, TortoiseSVN Log is pretty capable.

Comment: Thanks but i want to search based on content within the files as well

Answer (score 0):

FYI, After you download SvnQuery and SvnFind from http://svnquery.tigris.org/ you can include SvnQuery.dll in a C# project and write your own GUI:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using SvnQuery;
//...
    public string wad = @"C:\Data\Download\SvnQuery\App\svn.idx";
    public ICollection<string> GetSvnFolderList()
    {
        string search = "/";
        var idx = new SvnQuery.Index(wad);
        var res = idx.Query(search);
        IDictionary<string, int> lst = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (var item in res.Hits)
        {
            string folder = item.Path.Substring(0, item.Path.LastIndexOf("/"));
            lst[folder] = 1;
        }
        return lst.Keys;
    }
```

Comment: P.S.--The syntax for advanced text search within repository files is documented in the SvnFind Help file.  In my case:
    C:\Data\Download\SvnQuery\App\SvnFind\Help.htm